# Intel wireless not working at all

Tags: networking, 15.10, intel-wireless, firmware, rfkill

To start off I am very new to Ubuntu so when explaining do not use shortcuts please because I will not understand. So I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Hp Envy and the wireless card is not working. I have been hassling with it all day and I'm finally giving in to making a forum post. The Card is a Intel 7265 Wireless AC(revision61). I am currently attempting to install a newer firmware for it that I downloaded from intels website but I can not for the life of me figure out how to get the file into the firmware folder. So basically I'm making a plea to help me get the firmware installed and if that doesn't work provide more insight before I say goodbye to Ubuntu. Thanks in advance!

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Rfkill List
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[    2.089673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.092497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.093049] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.113852] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.148273] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    2.149810] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.150242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.240713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   14.008741] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.009388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.070823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.071356] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

After `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi`

```
rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited now

Comment: Run `sudo rfkill unbloack all`. If that does not help, post output of `dmseg | grep iwlwifi` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: But it looks like you did not enable wireless in Network Manager.

Comment: @pilot6 rfkill unblock all did not work. It just turns on bluetooth. When I try to turn it on in network manager nothing happens or it just switches to off immediately.

Comment: And what is your laptop model?

Comment: @Pilot6 Hp Envy M6 X360 w105dx

Comment: This is a bug that `acer_wmi` is loaded. See the answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried sudo modprobe and rkill unblock and it did not work, but my airplane mode button on my keyboard started working for wifi also and bluetooth. Is it a bug because it is specific to Acer model computers?

Comment: What does `rfkill list` show now?

Comment: @pilot6 edited question with output

Comment: It should work now. Enable it in Network manager. Do you see wireless APs?

Comment: I only see my phone that I tried using as a hotspot awhile back but didnt work. I also got an internal error after i rebooted the computer referrring to the network manager. I checked rfkill list and acer -wmi is back so I will try the permanent method you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable `acer_wmi` module by running:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

To set it permanently run this command:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

Comment: IT WORKS. I just rebooted again and everything works flawlessly now. Its detecting access points now and im connected to mine! Thank you so much for the help I appreciate it!

Comment: So you can accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left to show that it works.

Comment: And I suggest reporting this bug to launchpad.