# Wireless 7265 not working on ubuntu 16.04 + Asus K401U

Tags: wireless, asus, intel-wireless

I just bought a Asus K401U. Pretty net computer aside of the fact the Wifi is really not working with Ubuntu 16.04. While wifi are in the building, I still see nothing on my computer.

Below, I collected few diagnostics :

ifconfig -a:

```
yug@yug-pc:~$ ifconfig -a
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:5a:3a:8d:22:7f  
          inet addr:10.1.250.18  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4ee0:db4c:9436:1d18/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:47459302 (47.4 MB)  TX bytes:1833011 (1.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:472886 (472.8 KB)  TX bytes:472886 (472.8 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:53:60:f2:49:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

lspci, refkill list, etc/resolv.conf :

```
yug@yug-pc:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
yug@yug-pc:~$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

yug@yug-pc:~$ rfkill list
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
yug@yug-pc:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search SCTFICGRP
```

Demesg:

```
yug@yug-pc:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.822199] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.822213] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.822224] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.822689] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    3.828132] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.894906] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    3.894982] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.895173] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.986345] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    3.989171] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.993340] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
yug@yug-pc:~$ ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Jan  5 22:34 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 May 13  2015 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Aug  3  2015 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Mar 21 20:27 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Nov 24  2014 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Dec  2  2014 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 May 29 09:37 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 May 13  2015 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Aug  3  2015 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Mar 21 20:27 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
```

*EDIT* /lib/firmware | grep 7265

```
yug@yug-pc:~$  ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Jan  5 22:34 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 May 13  2015 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Aug  3  2015 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Mar 21 20:27 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Nov 24  2014 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Dec  2  2014 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 May 29 09:37 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode -> iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 May 13  2015 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Aug  3  2015 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Mar 21 20:27 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
```

I would appreciate any help. If you need me to get back more info back, I will send it back quickly.

See also [Intel wireless not working at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738423/) , [Can't connect wifi with Intel AC 7265 on Ubuntu 15.10, Asus ZenBook UX305](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726292/) (none seems a solid answer)

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi; sudo rfkill unblock all`. Does wireless work after that?

Comment: I ran it twice. I now have : $rfkill list  returning ```>3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no```

Comment: This looks like a bios problem. Try to reset bios to defaults. If that does not help, file a bug to launchpad.

Comment: @Pilot6: could you open an answer, I will complete its content and give you credit for this help since you provided me the key :)

Comment: Does it work after reboot?

Comment: It works (I think) since I made ```sudo rfkill block all; sudo rfkill unblock all```.  I think your advice solved my issue, it just needed to wait a bit my wifi to refresh, or my computer to sleep, or my computer to reboot. Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

1. Clap down your PC which then turn into sleeping mode.
2. Reopen it : it will awake and wifi will work.
   Don't ask why. Just do it.

---

**Previous answer :**

Ok. rfkill is your friend.

```
rfkill - tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices

SYNOPSIS
       rfkill [options] command

COMMANDS
       ...

       block index|type
              Disable the device corresponding to the given index.  type is one of "all",  "wifi",
              "wlan", "bluetooth", "uwb", "ultrawideband", "wimax", "wwan", "gps", "fm" or "nfc".

       unblock index|type
              Enable  the  device corresponding to the given index. If the device is hard-blocked,
              e.g. via a hardware switch, it will  remain  unavailable  though  it  is  now  soft-
              unblocked.
```

So to soft unblock all :

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

To **hard unblock**, find **on your keyboard a key or hardware switch**. For me, it was F2 with a plane icon. Press this key. Afterwhat :

```
$rfkill list 
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: That's a bit wierd, but it works at least.

Comment: I love the word "Don't ask why. Just do it." :D and it did solve my problem. Thanks! Never thought solution could be this simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I am using asus K501U and Ubuntu 16.04.

After I installed Ubuntu I also found my wifi disabled,
which is caused by hard blocked issue.

And I found that the "Clap computer and open" solution provided by [Hugolpz](https://askubuntu.com/users/158008/hugolpz) is working.

But as I keep searching,
I find the solution below also worked for me:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

the original post is [Asus k501U Wifi hard blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814133/asus-k501u-wifi-hard-blocked)