# Asus k501U Wifi hard blocked

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Gnome 3.

I get the error message `wifi hard blocked`.

My wireless network hardware:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
        Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
```

How can I fix this problem and unblock my wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Ubuntu
 14.04 LTS with Gnome 3, wifi was hard-blocked. I open the file and add the line `blacklist wmi` there

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

But after I run that to activate keyboard backlit `sudo sensors-detect` but I get

> backlit activated, wifi hard-blocked

So the solution that I found

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Comment: before: rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: Yes
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

now: rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: This is all very unclear..

Comment: which other details you want?
I'm new in linux OS family, just tell me how i can increase details for that post,
sorry for my English,
and thank u

Comment: @BreahnaDavid It is great now, just needed a little context ;)

Comment: @BreahnaDavid Please, consider to accept this answer. It is completely acceptable to accept own answers.